# MonoDevelop 7.3.3 on Fedora 27 can't find .NET Core 2.0 SDK

Tags: .net, linux, monodevelop, fedora-27

Trying to build a solution with a .NET Standard 2.0 library and a .NET Core 2.0 console app via MonoDevelop.

MonoDevelop pops up a dialog asking me to install the .NET Core 2.0 SDK and prompts me to visit this page: https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linuxfedora

Installed the dotnet 2.0 SDK from those instructions and verified that the 'dotnet' application can run from the console. Rebooted and restarted MonoDevelop and the same popup comes up, MonoDevelop isn't able to find the .NET Core 2.0 SDK.

I'm using MonoDevelop from a flatpak but I'm not sure if that should matter.

Does anyone know what steps are required to get this working or what might be missed?

Comment: https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/issues You can report it to the developers. Microsoft recommends JetBrains Rider or Visual Studio Code on Linux to develop .NET Core apps if you don't know yet.

Comment: Currently using MonoDevelop from FlatPak will not find the .NET Core sdk since FlatPak runs in a sandbox and does not have access to other files.

Comment: Looks like this is the bug in the tracker: https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/issues/3685

Comment: @MattWard unfortunately the latest version of MD in F27 is 5.x so I can't go the package route either...

Comment: https://apebox.org/wordpress/linux/1240

Comment: @MattWard very cool. I haven't chatted with directhex in years, its great to see he is still around and working on OSS stuff.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report (which has already been filed), not a question